# Lower bound of convex functions defined on compact intervals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

The problem is from Hörmander's “Notions of Convexity” (problem 1.1.2, page 2). Let $J,I$ be two compact intervals in $\mathbb R$, $J\subset I$ and $m, M$ two constants. Let $f: I \to \Bbb R$ be a convex function with $f\leq M$ in $I$ and $f\geq m$ in $J$. If $|J| + dist\,(J,\partial I)$ (length of $J$ + distance between $J$ and the boundary of $I$) is not zero, then show that

$$f(x)\geq M-(M-m)\frac{|I|}{|J| + dist\,(J,\partial I)}\,\,\forall x\in I.$$

If $x\in J$, the inequality works as $m\geq  M-(M-m)\frac{|I|}{|J| + dist\,(J,\partial I)}$, but the general case seems hard.

Comment: Without any conditions on $f$ this is false

Comment: @s.harp: What conditions on $f$ did you think of?

Comment: @MartinR your answer for example uses that $f$ is convex. That was the close-lying condition, but maybe the OP forgot to mention even more of them, would seem like a waste of time if it would turn out to require more than just convexity.

Comment: @s.harp: Yes, that is what I understood from the *title.* – But you are right, adding that information to the question *body* would probably be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote $I = [a, d]$ and $J = [b, c]$ with $a \le b \le c \le d$. The condition $|J| + dist(J, \partial I) > 0$ guarantees that $c > a$ and $d > b$.

You already figured out the case $x \in [b, c]$, so it remains to consider the cases $x \in [a, b]$ and $x \in [c, d]$.

Because of the symmetry, it suffices to consider the case $x \in [a, b]$. The function is convex, so that a lower bound for $f(x)$ is the value of the line joining $(b, f(b))$ and $(d, f(d))$:

$$
 f(x) \ge \frac{d-x}{d-b} f(b) + \frac{x-b}{d-b} f(d) \, .
$$
We know that $f(b) \ge m$ and $f(d) \le M$. This gives (note that the factor at $f(d)$ is *negative*):
$$
 f(x) \ge \frac{d-x}{d-b} m + \frac{x-b}{d-b} M
 = M - (M-m)\frac{d-x}{d-b} \, .
$$
Finally note that
$$
\frac{d-x}{d-b} = \frac{d-x}{(c-b)+(d-c)} \le \frac{|I|}{|J| + dist(J, \partial I)} \, .
$$